# How can I install upstart on debian 9?

Tags: debian, upstart

To demonize an app, I‌ used to use upstart. I know it is discarded from debian packages, but I still need it as I can not make my app run using systemd.

Currently, when I try to install it I get:

```
# apt install upstart
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Package upstart is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source
However the following packages replace it:
  systemd-sysv sysvinit-core

E: Package 'upstart' has no installation candidate
```

So appreciate your hints to install upstart.

Comment: Sorry, but this isn't going to be easy to do without extensive modification. Upstart is no longer supported by Debian. I suggest you ask a new question instead, asking how to get your program to work with systemd.

Comment: You can use upstart package from jessie repository.

Comment: @IporSircer how?

Comment: Add jessie repository to your `sources.list` then install it.

Comment: Installing Upstart from Jessie on Stretch is a *really* bad idea. You’ll need to deal with [all the bugs](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/pkgreport.cgi?archive=both;dist=oldstable;src=upstart) which were never fixed, plus all the new ones which have been introduced by changes in Debian 9 which Upstart isn’t ready for, and you’ll have to do so all on your own. @Ipor I would have expected you to know better than to suggest something like that :-/.

Comment: @Babr why can’t you make your app run using systemd?

Comment: @StephenKitt I don't know. It does not run node process. Perhaps I don't translate node parameters to systemd correctly.

Comment: As terdon suggested, I think you’d get more useful results if you asked a new question to find out how to convert your Upstart job to a systemd unit. It is certainly possible to run Node programs in systemd units, I’d imagine there’s a good chance yours can be run that way too...